# Compare 2 1-D dynamic array

Tags: vba, excel

I had 2 tables. The 1st table contains the department name and number of people, the other contains department name and some other information. I'm trying to copy the number of people from the 1st table to the 2nd table based on the department name.

However, the size of the table are not equal as for the 2nd table, the department name can appear more than once or even not at all.

Tables are from different worksheets.

**Example of Table 1**

[image]

**Example of Table 2**

[image]

I had successfully get the data from the column using dynamic array and pass between subs, but unable to compare when copy the value when match.

My codes structure

```
Sub getTable1()

    Dim dept, getNum As Variant
    Dim i,x As Long
    x = 0

    ReDim dept(1 To 1)
    ReDim getNum(1 To 1)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table1")
            For i= 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            x = x + 1
            ReDim Preserve dept(1 To x)
            ReDim Preserve getNum(1 To x)

            dept(x) = .Cells(i, "A").Value
            getNum(x) = .Cells(i, "B").Value

            Next x
    End With

    For i = 1 to x
        Call passValue(dept(i), getNum(i))
    Next

End Sub

Sub passValue(ByVal dept, getNum As Variant)

    Dim target As Variant
    ReDim target(1 To 1)

    Dim i, cnt, rowCnt As Long
    cnt = 0

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table2")
    For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

                cnt = cnt + 1
                ReDim Preserve target(1 To cnt)
                target(cnt) = .Cells(i, "D").Value
    Next i
    End With

    For i = 1 To cnt
        If target(i) = dept Then ' If match print result
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table2")
                For rowCnt = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
                .Cells(rowCnt, "E").Value = getNum ' Only print the last result
                Next
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you load the first into a dictionary and then use that to populate the 2nd dimension of the array holding the second table? If Dept is not unique in table 1 you can simply add to existing value. Are these set up as proper excel tables (as you appear to be reading from sheets named tableX? If there is a repeat of the dept in table 2 do you want the number repeated? e.g. IT 20, IT 20? And will you be writing this back out to the sheet? If so, where will the numbers go? And you could do this simply with a VLOOKUP, any reason why not?

Comment: Expressions such as  .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row should be in a variable so save revisiting the sheet and avoid ReDim if possible as you are making copies of the array which is expensive.

Comment: @QHarr 1. These are not proper table, only add auto filter. 2. If there is a repeat of the dept in table 2 I want the number to be repeated. 3. Yes, the value will be right back to the sheets, under **Others Column**. 4. I did these because I will send the sheet using `.MailEnvelope`. These are temporatery sheets, they will be deleted after the mail is sent.

Comment: Do you need the first two  ReDim ?

Comment: @QHarr Yes, In case in the future there's increase in the department. Seems like I had alot of problems need to solve one by one...

Comment: I would probably go with my first comment and use a dictionary to hold the values from sheet 1 (looping from start row to endrow adding to dictionary dept, count). Then read the second sheet into a 2D array. Simply loop the second array and use something like array2(x,2) = dict(array2(x,1)) to access and set the values.

Comment: @QHarr Thank you for showing the right direction! I would go and read the doc for dictionary, and continue from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of what I was describing, you probably want some error handling in case a dept appears in sheet `Table2` that is not in `Table1`:

```
Public Sub getTable1()

  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet
  Dim ws2 As Worksheet

  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Table1")
  Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Table2")

  Dim lastRowT1 As Long
  lastRowT1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in column A of first sheet

  Dim lastRowT2 As Long
  lastRowT2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in column A of second sheet

  Dim table1Arr()
  table1Arr = ws1.Range("A2:B" & lastRowT1).Value '1 to 4, 1 to 2  'read the range from A2:B to last used row in A e.g. A2:B6 into array creating a 2D array that starts at index 1. The table is now held in the array.

  Dim table2Arr()
  table2Arr = ws2.Range("A2:B" & lastRowT2).Value '1 to 3, 1 to 2 'read used range containing table 2 into an array.

  Dim table1Dict As New Scripting.Dictionary 'required reference to MS Scripting Runtime

  Dim i As Long

  For i = LBound(table1Arr, 1) To UBound(table1Arr, 1) 'loop the first dimension of array 1 i.e. the depts.

      If table1Dict.Exists(table1Arr(i, 1)) Then

        table1Dict(table1Arr(i, 1)) = table1Dict(table1Arr(i, 1)) + table1Arr(i, 2)   'if dept exists as a key in the dict then add the number of people from array 1 (i.e. from table 1) to the existing value. This handles potentially repeating depts in table1.

    Else

       table1Dict.Add table1Arr(i, 1), table1Arr(i, 2) 'if dept not already in dict, add the dept as a key to the dict and the number of people as the value.

    End If

 Next i

 For i = LBound(table2Arr, 1) To UBound(table2Arr, 1)  'next loop your table 2 array depts

     table2Arr(i, 2) = table1Dict(table2Arr(i, 1))  'as department names are spelt the same across both tables you can use the table2 dept names as the key to retrieve the dictionary values for that dept in the dictionary i.e. from table1. Then simply assign that to the Others column i.e.  table2Arr(i, 2) 

 Next i

End Sub
```

See [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)'s article on working with arrays. From that article you can see how to write back out to Table2 sheet the second array:

> Writing A Two Dimensional VBA Array To The Worksheet
>
> If you have a 2 dimensional array, you need to use Resize to resize
>   the destination range to the proper size. The first dimension is the
>   number of rows and the second dimension is the number of columns. The
>   code below illustrates writing an array (..table2Arr..) out to the worksheet
>   starting at cell (..A2..).

```
Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = ws2.Range("A2")
Destination.Resize(UBound(table2Arr, 1), UBound(table2Arr, 2)).Value = table2Arr
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain what does this mean `table1Arr = ws1.Range("A2:B" & lastRowT1).Value '1 to 4, 1 to 2`? I only know that it is a 2D array

Comment: This table1Arr = ws1.Range("A2:B" & lastRowT1).Value reads the range from sheet Table1 into an array (from first row under header to last row in column A). This creates the 2d array. The '1 to 4 , 1 to 2 was just a comment showing what the resulting array dimensions are for the example you have i.e. 2 dimensions, the first is 1 to 4 and the second is 1 to 2, ie 4 rows, 2 columns. When reading in direct from worksheet to an array the base option is 1 not 0 i.e. the array starts at 1 not at 0.